# 2 way to write Plotly.newPlot : is there a difference?

Tags: javascript, plotly

Can someone explain to me the difference between the following:

- `Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, data, layout, config)`
- `Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, obj)`

I thought it the two were the same but I get errors with the former on resize, which I do not encounterwhen using the latter.

Maybe the way the div is declared..?

Comment: If you're seeing an error with one and not the other, you'll have to post some code showing the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is not meant to be a difference between the two: https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot